# cypress cy.route not behaving consistently

Tags: javascript, cypress, stub, end-to-end

I am trying to stub out a route using cypress 5.2.  I have a simple function to do that:

```js
function mockAlertsResponses(){
  cy.route({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/api/polling/alerts/statistics*",
    response: {
      total: 2,
      ...
    }
  });
}
```

In one set of tests, this works just fine:

```js
describe("admin and read only permissions", () => {
  it ("all action bar items are enabled with admin permissions", () => {
    cy.login("user", "password");
    mockAlertsResponses();

    // Click alert to enable all buttons
    cy.get("#1-checkbox").click()

    cy.get("#mark-alert-button").should("be.enabled");
    cy.get("#delete-alert-button").should("be.enabled");
  });

  // ... a few more similar tests
});
```

However, in another set of tests, I use the same function:

```js
  it("Logs in and out", () => {
    cy.login("username", "password");
    mockAlertsResponses()
    cy.get("#vine-appbar").should("be.visible");
    cy.get("#info-button").click();
    cy.get("#info-menu-logout").click();
    cy.get("#login-button");
    cy.get("#vine-appbar").should("not.be.visible");
  });
```

In this second set of tests, the routes are not stubbing properly, leading to errors and test failures.  Here, you can see the route is not stubbed, but rather throws a 500 error:

[image]

I'm not sure what could be interfering here.  I'm a bit new to cypress and I'm not even sure where to begin debugging this.  Might the `cy.server` calls be interfering? Please let me know what more information we'd need to figure out why one set of stubs works and another doesn't.

If you're wondering, the login function has a call to `cy.server` and has its own `cy.route` as well:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("login", (username, password, admin = true) => {
  const response = admin ? <jwt1> : <jwt2>
 
  cy.server();
  cy.route({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/api/login",
    response
  });
  cy.visit("/logout");

  cy.visit("/");
  cy.wait(100);
  cy.get("#login-error").should("not.be.visible");
  cy.get("#login-username").type(username);
  cy.get("#login-password").type(password);
  cy.get("#login-button").click();
});
```

Comment: Does it help if you move the route setup before the request is fired? I.e. place `mockAlertsResponses()` before `cy.login()`

Comment: @OldSchooled it looks like `cy.get("#info-button").click();` is firing "/api/polling/alerts/statistics*" not the login.

Comment: @AloysiusParker, hmm, I thought it was the `visit` that occurs directly before since the click comes after the route. Could definitely be wrong though, was a guess based on the order but I know the order can sometimes be wonky.

Comment: Thank you guys for your suggestions.  Actually its not the any click event at all that triggers those calls - its the loading of the dashboard page in the app.  So @OldSchooled I cannot move the `mockAlertsResponses` before the login.  The user logs in, then the calls are made, data comes back, and the redux responds.  When the call fails, it triggers an error snackbar alert, which gets in the way of cypress clicking on other things in my test, and it fails.  @AloysiusParker I tried `route2`, but that doesn;t seem to change anything.  Nor does using a RegEx instead of a string for the url.

Comment: I do notice that the `/statistics` route is taking a param that doesn't seem to be getting parsed as part of the url string.  I'll add a picture in the original quesiton...maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: *** I cannot move the mockAlertsResponses before the login*** - not so, with `cy.route()` you are setting up an event listener of sorts, so it must be in place before the "event" occurs. Also `cy.server()` needs to precede `cy.route()`, so for experimentation put the call to  `mockAlertsResponses()` right before the `cy.visit()`.